# Why does my csv-writer use the data as the key and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, flask

I am using the csv library to write data collected via an html-form into a csv. The writer works only to certain extend as it doubles up my data as the key for the data, making it impossible to access it later. How can I fix my code?

Being a complete python beginner I, of course, tried looking up my problem, but I didn't find any fitting solution :/

```
# writes the valid data to the csv-file
with open("survey.csv", 'a') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=["name", "gender", "preference"])
    writer.writerow({"name": request.form.get("name"), "gender": request.form.get("gender"), "preference": request.form.get("pets")})
```

I expected an output like this (when iterating through the rows by using list(reader):

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Adrian'), ('gender', 'male'), ('preference', 'dogs')])
```

instead I am getting this:

```
OrderedDict([('Adrian', 'Adrian'), ('male', 'male'), ('dogs', 'dogs')])
```

Here is also my reader-code (maybe the problem is there):

```
with open("survey.csv","r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    participants = list(reader)
    for participant in participants:
        print(participant)
```

Comment: What do you get if you print the dictionary you are passing to `writerow()`? And what is the text content of the written csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are missing the headers, when writing with `csv.Dictwriter` you need to first write the headers using `writer.writeheader()`
in your case it appears that you are trying to append to the file, so I think you will need to have a initialization step in creating the file with the headers and then sub-sequentially appending to it. (otherwise you will be getting the headers as a new row every time you get a new form)

for example

```
In [2]: data
Out[2]:
[{'name': 'andrew', 'gender': 'm'},
 {'name': 'heather', 'gender': 'f'},
 {'gender': 'm', 'name': 'john'}]

In [3]: def start_file():
    ...:     with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    ...:         w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['name', 'gender'])
    ...:         w.writeheader()
    ...:

In [4]: def write_out(row):
    ...:     with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    ...:         w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['name', 'gender'])
    ...:         w.writerow(row)
    ...:

In [5]: start_file()

In [6]: for row in data:
    ...:     write_out(row)
    ...:

In [7]: with open('out.csv') as f:
    ...:     for row in csv.DictReader(f):
    ...:         print(dict(row))
    ...:
{'name': 'andrew', 'gender': 'm'}
{'name': 'heather', 'gender': 'f'}
{'name': 'john', 'gender': 'm'}
```